# How to reset a variable to NULL in PHP?

Tags: php, scripting, variables

I can use `isset($var)` to check if the variable is not defined or null. (eg. checking if a session variable has been set before)

But after setting a variable, how do I reset it to the default such that `isset($var)` returns `false`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `unset($var);`

Comment: Does this delete the reference *and* garbage collect the memory also?

Answer (score 26):

As nacmartin said, `unset` will "undefine" a variable. You could also set the variable to null, however this is how the two approaches differ:

```
$x = 3; $y = 4;
isset($x);  // true;
isset($y);  // true;

$x = null;
unset($y);
isset($x);  // false
isset($y);  // false

echo $x;  // null
echo $y;  // PHP Notice (y not defined)
```

Answer (score 23):

Further explanation:

While a variable can be null or not null, a variable can also be said to be set or not set.

to set a variable to null, you simply

```
$var = null;
```

This will make `$var` *null*, equivalent to `false`, `0` and so on. You will still be able to get the variable from `$GLOBALS['var']` since it is still defined / set. However, to remove a variable from the global and/or local namespace, you use the

```
unset($var);
```

This will make `$var` not set at all. You won't be able to find in `$GLOBALS`.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can set the variable to `null`:

```
<?php

$v= 'string';
var_dump(isset($v));
$v= null;
var_dump(isset($v));

?>
```

Comment: For a simple `$variable`, setting it to `null` is better for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As of php 7.2 directly setting a variable is depreciated. You should not use it in this fashion you should look into using unset instead. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

`unset($v);` will result in the same false when checking to see if the variable is null or unset.

```php
isset($v) === false 
is_null($v) === false
```